# How to improve my function that rounds floats to nearest 10 if 2 digit number, 100 if 3 digit number etc

Tags: algorithm, go

I am drawing bar charts and i've come across a tricky problem. How to programmatically set the max value for the y axis label depending on the max value for a given series. So if you had a bar with a value of 7, you might want the y axis to go up to 10

My approach is not ideal but works like this:

- Get a number to round, like 829
- Count the number of digits (3)
- Use a loop to convert to a string of 0s ("000")
- Add a 1 to the start of the string then convert to a float (1000)
- Find the difference (1000 - 829 = 171)
- Get the first digit of the difference (1) and then add that to the first digit of the float, with the remaining set to zero ("900"), then convert to a number (900)

This means that 725 will see a y axis max label number of 800, and 829 of 900

My code works, but I feel like it's a piece of crap with a hacky approach

I have to code for big numbers. For example, if the float I want to find the max value for is >10000 then take the first two digits, and add 1000 to it. If >100,000 add 10,000

**How can I improve here? I'm a little stuck, is my idea of converting to strings even right?!**

Full code here:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {

    myFloat := 899175.0

    x := getMaxYAxisValueForChart(myFloat)
    fmt.Println("The number to find the maximum value for is: ", myFloat)
    fmt.Println("This should be the max value for the y axis: ", x)
}

func getMaxYAxisValueForChart(float float64) (YAxisMaximum float64) {
    //Convert to string with no decimals
    floatAsString := fmt.Sprintf("%.f", float)

    //Get length of the string float
    floatAsStringLength := len(floatAsString)

    //For each digit in the string, make a zero-string
    stringPowerTen := "0"
    for i := 1; i < floatAsStringLength; i++ {
        stringPowerTen += "0"
    }

    //Add a 1 to the 0 string to get the difference from the float
    stringPowerTenWithOne := "1" + stringPowerTen

    //Convert the number string to a float
    convertStringPowerTenToFloat := ConvertStringsToFloat(stringPowerTenWithOne)

    //Get the difference from the denominator from the numerator
    difference := convertStringPowerTenToFloat - float

    //We want to isolate the first digit to check how far the float is (100 is far from 1000) and then correct if so
    floatAsStringDifference := fmt.Sprintf("%.f", difference)
    runes := []rune(floatAsStringDifference)
    floatAsStringDifferenceFirstDigit := string(runes[0])

    //For the denominator we want to take away the difference that is rounded to the nearest ten, hundred etc
    runes = []rune(stringPowerTen)
    differenceLastDigitsAsString := ""
    if difference < 10 {
        differenceLastDigitsAsString = "1"
    } else if difference < 30 && difference < 100 {
        differenceLastDigitsAsString = "0"
    } else {
        differenceLastDigitsAsString = floatAsStringDifferenceFirstDigit + string(runes[1:])
    }

    //Convert the number difference string from total to a float
    convertDifferenceStringPowerTenToFloat := ConvertStringsToFloat(differenceLastDigitsAsString)

    YAxisMaximum = convertStringPowerTenToFloat - convertDifferenceStringPowerTenToFloat

    //If float is less than 10,0000
    if float < 10000 && (YAxisMaximum-float >= 500) {
        YAxisMaximum = YAxisMaximum - 500
    }

    if float < 10000 && (YAxisMaximum-float < 500) {
        YAxisMaximum = YAxisMaximum
    }

    //If number bigger than 10,000 then get the nearest 1,000
    if float > 10000 {

        runes = []rune(floatAsString)
        floatAsString = string(runes[0:2])
        runes = []rune(stringPowerTen)
        stringPowerTen = string(runes[2:])
        runes = []rune(stringPowerTenWithOne)
        stringPowerTenWithOne = string(runes[0:(len(stringPowerTenWithOne) - 2)])

        YAxisMaximum = ConvertStringsToFloat(floatAsString+stringPowerTen) + ConvertStringsToFloat(stringPowerTenWithOne)
    }

    if float > 10000 {

        runes = []rune(floatAsString)
        floatAsString = string(runes[0:2])
        runes = []rune(stringPowerTen)
        stringPowerTen = string(runes[:])
        runes = []rune(stringPowerTenWithOne)
        stringPowerTenWithOne = string(runes[0:(len(stringPowerTenWithOne))])

        YAxisMaximum = ConvertStringsToFloat(floatAsString+stringPowerTen) + ConvertStringsToFloat(stringPowerTenWithOne)
    }

    return YAxisMaximum
}

func ConvertStringsToFloat(stringToConvert string) (floatOutput float64) {
    floatOutput, Error := strconv.ParseFloat(stringToConvert, 64)
    if Error != nil {
        fmt.Println(Error)
    }

    return floatOutput
}
```

---

**Here is the solution based off of Matt Timmermans answer, but converted to work in Go:**

```
func testing(float float64) (YAxisMaximum float64) {
    place := 1.0
    for float >= place*10.0 {
        place *= 10.0
    }
    return math.Ceil(float/place) * place
}
```

Comment: Improve in what way? What specifically are your concerns with this code? As written this post seems better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ than SO.

Comment: I'm unsure of how to futureproof it without hardcoding. For example I am basically doing an if statement where I say "if number is 100 to 1000 then add 100 to the first digit of your number and set the rest to zero", "if between 1000 and 10000...."

Comment: If that makes sense?

Comment: Man, I just cannot seem to ask positive rep questions

Comment: You could probably work something out with a loop using `for i = 10; ; i = i * 10` to iterate in orders of magnitude. You also probably want to familiarize yourself with the modulo operator `%`, as doing all this numeric logic using strings is probably sub-optimal.

Comment: That seems like a much smarter way of handling it, thanks a lot - I don't think the string manipulation is clever either, but I couldn't think of another way at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, that's a pretty complicated procedure you have.  This is how I would do it if the numbers aren't enormous.  I don't know go, so I'm going to guess about how to write it in that language:

```
func getMaxYAxisValueForChart(float float64) {

    place := 1.0;
    while float >= place*10.0 {
        place *= 10.0;
    }
    return math.Ceil(float/place) * place;
}
```

Comment: If I can transfer what you've done into Go easily, then yeah... what a mess I created!

Comment: Edited my answer to the Go version of what you have, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Take the length of the string and calculate that 10 to the power of that length

Or...better take the Log base 10, get the integer part, add 1 and then return that to the power of 10 :)

```
    import (
        "fmt"
        "math"
    )

    //func PowerScale(x int) int64{
    //   return int64(math.Pow(10,float64(len((fmt.Sprintf("%d",x))))))
    //}

    func PowerScale(x int) int64 {
     return int64(math.Pow(10,float64(int(math.Log10(float64(x))+1))))
}

    func main() {
        fmt.Println(PowerScale(829))
        fmt.Println(PowerScale(7))
    }
```

Comment: ...yes there is :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the magnitude of a number using Math.Log10

```
int magnitude = (int)Math.Pow(10, (int)Math.Log10(value));
```

Use that to divide the number down, calculate ceiling and then scale it back up.

*No strings, no while loops.*

Comment: snap.   I am wondering if there is some "print the number, count the digits" that is faster than doing Logs.  Not sure ICBA benchmarking it though.  Doing it this way is more elegant

Comment: Hmm... I think this actually always works OK (neglecting the overflow), but it could use a comment explaining why the result is valid even when the log is rounded up, because `Log10` returns a float result that is greater than the exact value.

Answer (score 1):

Since 829 is an int, or can be cast to, a pure integer solution :

```
func getMaxYAxisValueForChart(int int64) {
    base := 10;
    while int > base*10 {
        base := 10 * base; 
    }
    return int + (base - int) % base;
}
```